# 100% viewport layout with header/footer and big text in the body without overflow scrollbars

Tags: html, css, layout

I need to make a layout like the following.

[image: Layout]

Basically this should take the 100% of the viewport (no unused space, no scrollbars) no matter which size is the browser window.
The text needs to be big enough to occupy as most of the body section as possible, but without overflowing it. So, no scrollbars at all.

The text is dynamic and it's around 160 characters (depending on where the closest white-space is) or less.
I've tried using the vw, vh, vmin and vmax for font-size but that's not enough. Too big and the text overflows in some ratios. Too small and there's too much empty space.

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.0 and I don't mind using javascript solutions as long as they have good performance.

Any ideas?

Comment: try the demo here if that's what you are after -- http://gschoppe.com/projects/jSlabify/.

Comment: I've already tried jSlabify but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **font-size: calc(2vw + 4vmin);**
It is experimental, but on pure CSS. Just play with variables (vw, vh, vmin and vmax) and find optimal expression.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -o-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-lines: single;
  -moz-box-lines: single;
  -o-box-lines: single;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column nowrap;
  -ms-flex-flow: column nowrap;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  background-color: #333;
}
header {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f2f4f3;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -o-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -o-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
main {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -o-box-flex: 1;
  box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #a9927d;
  font-size: calc(2vw + 4vmin);
  overflow: hidden;
}
footer {
  height: 60px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -o-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -o-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #5e503f;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<main> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, itaque similique dolorum nostrum natus, officiis reiciendis rem modi placeat harum dolore quidem ab, in quisquam optio corporis, sit nam dolor!</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Accuracy in pixels will always be off because the letters do not have an equal width in pixels.

Set a large font for the characters so they overflow within the content area. Get the content area inner height, get the scroll height (this is set by the overflowed text) and loop subtracting 1 pixel until the scroll height is not greater than inner height of the content area.

In the CSS you can have any font size as long as its a big size so the letters overflow.  Match that size to the loop counter.

This works with any amount of characters, sometimes you will notice a gap at the bottom. This is because there is a difference of 1px between the overflow and the font size minimum to fit the content area. What that means is if you increase the font by 1 or 2 pixels when you see the gap you will get an overflow.

**Demo**

https://jsfiddle.net/pu770tdh/

**Jquery / JS**

```
for (i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
    var size = $(".content").css('font-size');
    size = size.replace('px', '');
    size = parseInt(size) - 1
    if ($('.content')[0].scrollHeight > $('.content').innerHeight()) {
        $(".content").css("font-size", size + "px")
    }
}

$(window).resize(function () {
    $(".content").css("font-size", "300px")
    for (i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
        var size = $(".content").css('font-size');
        size = size.replace('px', '');
        size = parseInt(size) - 1
        if ($('.content')[0].scrollHeight > $('.content').innerHeight()) {
            $(".content").css("font-size", size + "px")
        }
    }
})
```